# MYSQL: Count for every customer's visit

Tags: mysql

I am having problem to figure out how to create a query for this scenario:

Here is updated version of my question.

I have 3 tables.

```
`customers`: `id` , `name` , `address`

`cars`: `id` , `license_nr` , `make` , `customer_id`

`services`: `id` , `car_id` , `description`
```

Every time a customer comes for a service a new record made in `services` table. I want to know counts of services for each customer. There is no direct relation between in `services` and `customers`.

EDIT: Correction of a column name in services table.

Comment: And where is your code...? BTW, it's really simple ;-)

Comment: @KenanZahirovic I really don't have a code yet! Can you just give me an example on that? :)

Comment: If you don't have any code, at least show the table structure.

Comment: You have a problem with normalization of your database model. Relation between "cars" and "customers" is 1:1, which means that you can put it all in one table. In fact, much better solution is to move "customer_id" from "cars" table to "services" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I will answer my own question. Maybe someone else will need this. Thank you all for your efforts.

```
SELECT customers.name, COUNT(*) AS visit_count 
FROM services
JOIN cars ON cars.id = services.car_id
JOIN customers ON customer.id = cars.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_id
```

I get the result I want.

```
name         | visit count
Amal Hopkins |     1
Dean Leach   |     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated solution based on the updated question:

```
select count(s.id) as service_tickets, cust.id, cust.name, cust.address 
from customers cust 
left join cars c on c.customer_id = cust.id
left join services s on s.car_id = c.id
group by cust.id
```

I updated it so it would return 0 for customers who have no services on their cars.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY customer;
```

UPDATE:

If visit means a row in services table, then we are OK because we simply need to count rows in services table. Foreign keys are not a problem. In fact, we can use join to see customer's name. So, the syntax should be:

```
SELECT s.CustomerID, c.Name, COUNT(*) FROM services s
join customer c on c.id=s.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerID, c.Name
```

Comment: Kenan, thank you for your effort! But there is no direct relation / association between `services` and `customers` tables. I updated my question.